# Managed Metadata for Author field of Modern Site Page

Tags: sharepoint-online, modern-pages

Is there any specific managed metadata property for the below "Author" field which is displayed under Modern Site Page "Title" area.

[image]

We have a custom search(SPFX PnP Search ) where we are showing that author field value on Document Card control.

[image]

We have configured the managemetadata as "Author" but  "search" is showing "Created By" value[My name] instead of showing the name which we mentioned in the Author's field under Title area.

I have re-indexed the site many times,still it is showing created by value only.
Please help me on this.

Answer (score 1):

The Author in the Modern site page is stored in a hidden field _AuthorByline. This field is not mapped to a managed property by default:

[image]

You can map the _AuthorByline crawled property to a RefinableString100, for example like so:

[image]

I would also add an alias for the RefinableString100 managed property:

[image]

**Note:** You can use any of the pre-created managed properties starting from RefinableString001. RefinableString100 was used for an example.

Comment: Thank you for the response Denis!!!

Actually, the exact reason  why the mentioned user name is not showing in  search results is .On the page the "Author Byline" is getting changed. But in "Site Pages" library for that specific list item when I checked the "Author Byline" column  was empty. I manually updated that column in the library,then mentioned user name got updated in search results.